# Не работает WebSocket (io.sockets.on("connection") не реагирует на действия)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Сервер:

```
let express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    server = require("http").Server(app),
    io = require("socket.io")(server);

server.listen(3000);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("...")
});

io.sockets.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.emit("hello", "user")
});
```

Клиент:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://.../socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket");
ws.onmessage = e => console.log(e.data);
```

Многоточие я специально поставил.
onmessage срабатывает только один раз и выводит что-то типа 0{"sid":"...","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}.
Раньше работало require("socket.io").listen, но сейчас это почему-то равно undefined (теперь там есть только "Server").

Что делать? :(

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался!
Нужно было писать не `npm install socket.io`, а `npm install socket.io@2.3.0`

Comment: Ставить старую версию вместо новой? Сомнительная идея